# Conditional types without a shared param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to make my props be either type A, or B. For example

```
export default function App() {
  type Checkbox = {
    type: "checkbox";
    checked: boolean;
  };

  type Dropdown = {
    type: "dropdown";
    options: Array<any>;
    selectedOption: number;
  };

  type CheckboxOrDropdown = Checkbox | Dropdown;

  const Component: FC<CheckboxOrDropdown> = (props) => {
    return <>"...correct component"</>;
  };

  // these returns are just examples
  return <Component type="checkbox" checked={true} />;
  return <Component type="dropdown" options={[]} selectedOption={0} />;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-shockley-ul2xg?file=/src/App.tsx)

How can I achieve the same, but without the "type" prop? So that TS recognizes the type based on other props?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrGalm) work for you ? However, I think that [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9pXow) version is less verbose

Comment: So you want a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) but _without_ the discriminant?

Comment: @captain-yossarian huh, I actually like the second option. Is there a way to make it this readable not using FC?

Comment: @jonrsharpe basically. By the tone of the question, I'm assuming it's not really doable/is a bad practice? ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload your component. By overloading here I mean intersection of two functional components:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  type Checkbox = {
    checked: boolean;
  };

  type Dropdown = {
    options: Array<any>;
    selectedOption: number;
  };


  const Component: FC<Checkbox> & FC<Dropdown> = (props) => {
    return <>"...correct component"</>;
  };

  return [<Component checked={true} />, <Component  options={[]} selectedOption={0} />];
}
```

This is the less verbose version I know.

If you have a lot of component types and you don't want to manually intersect them, you can use [distributivity](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  type Checkbox = {
    checked: boolean;
  };

  type Dropdown = {
    options: Array<any>;
    selectedOption: number;
  };

  // credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
  type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
  ) => void
    ? I
    : never;

  type Overload<T> = UnionToIntersection<T extends any ? FC<T> : never>

  const Component: Overload<Checkbox | Dropdown> = (props) => {
    return <>"...correct component"</>;
  };

  return [<Component checked={true} />, <Component options={[]} selectedOption={0} />];
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mMV5kW)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!